# How do I get my 6yr old to stop pooping her pants

Tags: potty-training

So my 6yr old girl poops her pants at least once a day and normally it happens when she doesn't get what she wants or if the tv is on.
We took her tv time away when she did this and then we made it to 5 days then she didn't get her way and pooped.

I feel like she does it out of spite and laziness. We have had her checked and she is all fine and doesn't do this at school.

Her counselor though said we should stop punishing her when she does this and ignore it. And now that we are doing that she has gotten so much worse it's actually frustrating.

Any advice on how I can get this to stop?

Comment: what does she say about this occasion?

Comment: Please use punctuation. At the moment this question is very hard to understand.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that this isn't laziness, but an issue of manipulating you to do what she wants. I can certainly understand why you want to eliminate the behavior. The best way to tackle this could be as simple as giving her the exact opposite of what she wants (when she does it).

(Instant bedtime, for example...)
Force her to get into the tub, into pajamas, and then it's bedtime, immediately after the event. No matter what time it is. No objections allowed. No stories, no nothing. If she wants to act like a baby, treat her like one. Period. Then you can go back to enjoy whatever she objected to.

It might not be an instant fix, but not giving her what she wants is key. I will advise you to be careful. If she figured out how to manipulate you in this way, she will likely come up with an alternate way to manipulate you in the future. Just don't give in and don't give up. You are the parent and you are the one paying the bills.

Good Luck!

Comment: My best guess is, this will just escalate the issue into an all  out power struggle. Do you have some data or hands-on experience to back up this suggestion ?

Comment: I have experience with people of all ages who use manipulation to get what they want. Once they realize that it won't work, they either stop misbehaving, or they switch to a new tactic. Neither my own son, nor any of the several children that have been in my care, found satisfaction in getting their own way (by misbehaving). It's certainly not fun to deal with, but once you do, life becomes far less "dramatic".